# c# I need to perform this SQL Select to LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have this Select:

```
SELECT (MyFields)
    FROM table1 T1 
    INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.ID_t2 = T1.ID_T1 
    INNER JOIN 
    table3 t3 on t3.ID_t3=T1.ID_T1 and Left(t3.Other_t3_field,5)=t2.Another_t2_field
WHERE (Conditions)
```

Then, I tried in C#:

```
var query = from T1 in table1
    join t2 in table2 on T1.ID_T1 equals t2.ID_t2
    join t3 in **table3** on T1.ID_T1 equals v.ID_t3
    join t4 in **table3** on t2.Other_t2_field equals Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Left(t2.Another_t3_field, 5)
    where (Conditions)
    select new 
    {
        (My fields)
    };
```

Both works, but my C# query have more results then SQL Select, I don't know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: LINQ to what? Linq to Objects, SQL, EF, NHibernate? The question would make sense only if you used LINQ to Objects. With ORMs you should define the relations and let the provider generate the joins

Answer (score 1):

Well I'd *start* by changing the join on table 3 in the C# - use an anonymous type to join on multiple fields:

```
join t3 in table3 on new { Id = t1.ID_T1, X = t2.AnotherT2Field.Substring(0, 5) }
  equals new { Id = t3.ID_T3, X = t3.OtherT3Field.Substring(0, 5) }
```

(I'd hope you can use `Substring` instead of `Left` here... it's much more idiomatic C#.)

Comment: Indeed, that extra join was the problem. I really thank you for the help :D

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple join conditions with an anonymous type:

```
var query = from T1 in table1
    join t2 in table2 on T1.ID_T1 equals t2.ID_t2
    join t3 in **table3** on new { 
                                   ID = T1.ID_T1, 
                                   substring = t2.Other_t2_field
                                 } equals new 
                                 {
                                   ID = v.ID_t3,
                                   substring = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Left(t2.Another_t3_field, 5)
                                 }
    where (Conditions)
    select new 
    {
        (My fields)
    };
```

As Jon Skeet mentioned: you can also use `Substring` instead of `Left`.